# android store reject for his-res icon and title

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I got some problems with upgrading my app to Android store. Android store is keep rejecting with the following reason.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhR94.png)

```
Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

   Hi-res icon
   Title
```

the previous version was ok and now how come they are keep rejecting for it. Where can I change the
Hi-re icon and Title in Android studio.

Best Rgds,
joozer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove any special character or emoji from app title (from all languages) in the store
- Remove any brand names from your titles
- The store icon must have enough spaces (margins) from the border
- remove any copyrighted material from your store icon